# Storing data in an Array and outputting that data

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that stores data in an Array from the user and outputs that data.

For example:

An input:

```
Happy HAPPY@foo.com
```

The output:

```
 NAME:  Happy        
 EMAIL: HAPPY@foo.com
```

I was hoping someone could look at what I've got so far and give me a pointer on how to continue. I know I have to use the scanner class and  scan.nextLine, I'm not sure what comes next. I understand I don't have much, I'm not looking for someone to complete this, but maybe someone who can give me some pointers or point me in the right direction. I believe I have the correct base to my program.

My Code So Far:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Program5 {

      void loadContacts()
      {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());

        scan.close();
      }

      void printContacts()
      {

      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Program5 program5 = new Program5();
        program5.loadContacts();
        program5.printContacts();

    }

}
```

Comment: "*I'm lost right now.*" -  where and how exactly. Please provide more details on what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Store whatever you have scanned in a class level array. And then iterate over the items in the array and append "NAME" or "EMAIL" according to your requirement. You might want to add validation to the strings but then its upto you.

Comment: Start trying to store the string read from nextLine into a variable and split the text in two parts (name and email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better name the class "person" or like this, but nevermind for the explanation :

```
public class Program5 {
    private String name;
    private String mail;

    public Program5(){}

    void loadContacts(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a name and a mail like this : name email@email.com (separate with ' ')");
        String[] line = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
        while(line.length!=2){
            System.out.println("Again, enter a name and a mail like this : name email@email.com (separate with ' ')");
            line = scan.nextLine().split("/");
        }
        this.setName(line[0]);
        this.setMail(line[1]);
        scan.close();
    }

    void printContacts() {
        System.out.println("NAME : "+this.name+"\nEMAIL : "+this.mail);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program5 program5 = new Program5();
        program5.loadContacts();
        program5.printContacts();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

In the `load`you ask the user, check it he enter 2 element separate by '/' and if yes store them as attributes to be able to get them in another method ;)

Comment: What do you mean by separate with ' '. Like for example 'doc' 'doc@foo.com'?

Comment: it's a space, juste like your INPUT example

Answer (score 0):

You should have a global varible to store the name and the email. Try adding these lines on the top of the code. after `public class Program5 {`.

```
private String Name, Email;
```

The you must assing this values to `void loadContacts()`. Spliting the string you read.

```
void loadContacts()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    String arr[] = input.split("\\s+");
    Name = arr[0];
    Email = arr[1];
    scan.close();
}
```

And finally on `void printContacts()`.

```
void printContacts()
{
    System.out.println("NAME: " + Name + "\nEMAIL: " + Email);
}
```

Here is the code runnig: http://ideone.com/mjyfHK

Answer (score 0):

You can do a variety of things.

1. You can make `loadContacts()` and `printContacts()` static methods, and also change `loadContacts()` so that it returns an Array or 2D array or however you choose to represent a name-email pair. Then change `print`Contacts()` to take in that type and iterate through that Array to print out each name/email pair. This solution is a bit more work but you won't have to create an object of the same class within the main method of that class.

or

2. You can keep your method as they are and instead create a new field for the program class, called `contacts` and it would be of the type that you choose for representing name/email pairs. You would add items to `contacts` in `loadContacts()` and iterate through it in `printContacts()`. Then you don't have to change anything in your main method.